# Firebase firestore onUpdate trigger event not running for some documents only

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

For two documents, in my firestore collection, my `onUpdate` function will not trigger. It will for 99% of the documents in the collection, but for only two documents, it will not. Google Cloud function logs for this function don't even show a function started/stopped info entry for documents that won't trigger. Again, most docs will show the `functions.logger.info()` results, but some docs will not. These are documents that already exist that are not triggering `onUpdate` when data in the document is updated.

[Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) indicate that an onUpdate is "Triggered when a document already exists and has any value changed."

**Has anyone else run into `onUpdate()` not firing only for specific document id's?** I have submitted a support case to the Google Cloud trigger event team, so I'll post any updates I receive, but this is beyond odd, because 99% of my documents, which all have the same structure, trigger an `onUpdate`, but only specific documents will not. Very frustrating and frustrating that there are no logs of any issues at all. Something on the Google firestore side of things is blocking specific documents from running the function.

Incidentally, the document id's are the uid found in the firebase auth db for users. There seems to be a possible connection between sign in issues (firebase auth) and doc id's, which are uid's, that will not trigger via `onUpdate()`. However, I cannot find any docs that would support uid's, being used as doc id's, from being prevented to trigger events in firestore collections, when there are firebase auth issues for a uid. Anyway, this is my theory for the moment since there are zero logs for these documents that will not trigger an `onUpdate`.

**Excerpt of my onUpdate function:**

```js
exports.updated = functions
  .region('us-east4')
  .firestore.document('myCollection/{uid}')
  .onUpdate(async (data, context) => {
    try {
      functions.logger.info(`onUpdate triggered for uid ${context.params.uid}`, context)

      const before = data.before.data()
      const after = data.after.exists ? data.after.data() : null

      functions.logger.info(`before data for uid: ${context.params.uid}`, before)
      functions.logger.info(`after data for uid: ${context.params.uid}`, after)
    } catch (error) {
      functions.logger.error(error)
    }
  })
```

Comment: What happens if you add the following line at the end of the `try()` block: `return null;`. Without that it is possible that the Cloud Function platform kills your CF before it executes the work. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions for more explanations. However, if this behaviour is possible I would be surprised it occurs all the time with the same specific documents.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec my excerpt does not show my returns, but they are there. I simply have `return`, null is not needed. Also, just got off Google Meet with Firebase rep and he confirmed they are having many internal issues with Firestore. So users having sign in issues for specific users or onUpdate not running, the internal issues they are working are likely culprits. Bottom line, bugs in firestore.